# How to get value from AJAX or Post responseText for Java1.7 Selenium 2.53.1

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

It perfectly works with Java 8. But I have to use the same with 1.7. Does any one know solution? I have very simple request look like:

```
$.post("URL",{ time: '2020-01-10 10:15', queue: 1, schedule: 2}).done(function (data) {
          console.log(data); });
```

It is returning me `OK` or `FAIL` on console of Chrome, but I'm not able to get it for Java Variable. (for my automation tests).

With Java 1.7 and Selenium 2.53.1. Execute is returning list of function like: `readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType:`.

What is Wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible that you confound java/javascript ?
Your code looks like a jQuery snippet

Comment: Yes, but picture is: during the test based on Selenium Java, I have to Execute JavaScript on the post. So Java code look like:
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String response = (String) js.executeScript("return $.post(..)"); with Java 8 and Selenium 3.x.x I'm getting the response text, but with Java 7 and Selenium 2.53.1 looks like something different required.

Comment: found the answer to my question. The problem is with old Chrome and ChromeDriver. Starting from 7x version of chrome it is possible to read response from the console. In My case this is response of JavaScript. Before this version no chance to get information of response text, only something like status (is any Ajax is still active or not). Thanks